# How to select the number of entities in association in Doctrine query builder?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm filtering a table of clients using doctrine query builder
Client entity have a field $orders

```
/**
 * Bidirectional - One-To-Many (INVERSE SIDE)
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orders", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist"} )
 *
 */
private $orders;
```

and Order entity have a field $client

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", cascade="persist", inversedBy="orders")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 *
 * */
private $client;
```

So in my Client repository I'm trying to select clients with less than or equal to a value.

```
    $qb->andWhere("client.orders <= :value");
```

However I cannot access to the numbers of orders.

```
    $qb->andWhere("count(client.orders) <= :value");
    $qb->andWhere("client.orders.count <= :value");
```

Comment: try with `$qb->having("count(client.orders) <= :value");`

Comment: This is the error, 
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'orders) <= :value': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.